# ExpressJs request return body as empty object {}

Tags: express, mongoose

I want to update document, but my request return empty object {}
I use Insomnia
`/createProfile` is endpoint to create profile data right after registration

```
router.post('/createProfile', auth, async (req: any, res: any) => {
  try {
    const { name, gender, birthday, about } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body); // {}
    console.log(req.user); // user ID

    const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(req.user, {
      name,
      gender,
      birthday,
      about,
    });
    return res.json(updatedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
});
```

auth

```
const auth = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    const token = req.header('x-auth-token');

    if (!token) {
      return res
        .status(401)
        .json({ msg: 'No authentication token, access denied' });
    }
    const { JWT_SECRET } = process.env;

    // @ts-ignore
    const verified = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET);
    if (!verified) {
      return res
        .status(401)
        .json({ msg: 'No authentication token, access denied' });
    }

    // @ts-ignore
    req.user = verified.id;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
};
```

and index.ts

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
/* eslint-disable no-void */
import chalk from 'chalk';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import usersRouter from './routes/userRouter';

dotenv.config();

const { MONGO_URI } = process.env;

mongoose.set('returnOriginal', true);
// @ts-ignore
void mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error);
mongoose.connection.once('open', () =>
  console.log(chalk.yellow.bold('MongoDB connected ')),
);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.listen(<number>PORT, () => {
  console.log(
    chalk.blue.bold(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT} `),
  );
});

// doesn't need since docker image have tini package manager
// process.on('SIGTERM', (): void => {
//   process.exit();
// });

//set up routes
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

Comment: How is the request to `/createprofile` being sent?  Is it is form post?

Comment: @jfriend00 I test it with insomnia, on the frontend I will use axios https://i.imgur.com/mVfnCHB.png

Comment: So, what is the content-type of the request data you are sending?    One reason `req.body` might be empty is that the content type is not JSON because the only body parser you show installed is `app.use(express.json());` so if the content-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` or anything but `application/json`, then it won't get read and parsed and `req.body` will be empty.  You can add `console.log(req.headers)` to see what the incoming `content-type` is.

Comment: I just add Content-Type: application/json to headers in insomnia and works, tanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your content-type in the incoming POST is not `application/json`, then your middleware `app.use(exprss.json())` will not read and parse the incoming body and `req.body` will end up empty.

So, an empty `req.body` on an incoming POST is nearly always because the incoming content-type does not match the middleware you have installed.  Sometimes you have to fix this by setting the correct content-type on the POST and sometimes you have to fix this by installing the proper middleware to parse the content-type you are using.